# Javascript - Merge indexes of array into one object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**INPUT**

```
[0]: [{}, {}],
[1]: [{}, {}],
[2]: [{}]
```

I have index 0, 1 and 2 with array of objects. Now I need to merge all these index values into a single array of object

**Expected O/P**

`[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]`

Comment: use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting an array of single object arrays, to an array of objects](/q/63344699/4642212). Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
  [{
    key1: "value1"
  }, {
    key2: "value2"
  }],
  [{
    key3: "value3"
  }, {
    key4: "value4"
  }],
  [{
    key5: "value5"
  }]
];

arr = arr.flat();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's just one solution like you need:

```
let a = {
  0: [{}, {}],
  1: [{}, {}],
  2: [{}]
}

let values = []
for (var x in a)
{
    a[x].map(p => values.push(p))
}
console.log(values)  //[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Make sure to handle each case, validate if it's an array then loop over it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a one liner using the `reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
  0: [{}, {}],
  1: [{}, {}],
  2: [{}]
}

const arr = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => ([...acc, ...curr]), [])
console.log(arr)
```